# How can I supress Vue/Webpack dev server proxy error messages in the terminal?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, cypress

My application uses an end-to-end testing framework (Cypress) that outputs results in the
terminal. When testing changes to frontend code, I use the Vue dev server's
`proxy` option to route API requests to a remote backend server.

Due to the high load of requests pummeling this test server, our application
frontend expects certain requests to fall through, and it is able to
intelligently handle retrying a given failed API call. However, the proxy
handler doesn't know this, and as a result the console log becomes cluttered
with `ECONNRESET` proxy errors, as can be seen below.

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/XXXXXX from local.myapp.io:3000 to https://myapp-dev.appspot.com.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/XXXXXX from local.myapp.io:3000 to https://myapp-dev.appspot.com.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/XXXXXX from local.myapp.io:3000 to https://myapp-dev.appspot.com.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/XXXXXX from local.myapp.io:3000 to https://myapp-dev.appspot.com.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).

    ✓ C22756 should be disabled when no events exist (8018ms)
    ✓ C22757 should be clickable when events exist (2250ms)
  Widget Settings

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/XXXXXX from local.myapp.io:3000 to https://myapp-dev.appspot.com.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).

    ✓ C22758 should have name, date range, and account fields (2435ms)
```

These errors can get quite verbose and tend to hide/obscure the more laconic
test output, making it difficult to scan and nearly impossible to copy
effectively.

**Is there any way to suppress these error messages from the dev server/proxy
handler?** Ideally, there would be some form of configuration in an NPM script
or the Vue/Webpack config JS file that would allow me to ignore or hide these
errors just when running our test suite.

For reference, here is the config object being passed to the `vue.config.js`
file's `devServer` property:

```js
const config = {
    allowedHosts: ['localhost', 'local.myapp.io'],
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'root/of/frontend/code'),
    disableHostCheck: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    https: {
        cert: LocalDevCert.getCert(),
        key: LocalDevCert.getKey()
    },
    port: 3000,
    proxy: {
    '^(?!/(js|modules|img))': {
        target: 'https://myapp-dev.appspot.com',
        cookieDomainRewrite: 'local.myapp.io',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: true,
        bypass (req, res) {
            const xsrfToken = uuid();
            if (req.headers.accept && req.headers.accept.includes('html')) {
                res.cookie('MyXSRFToken', xsrfToken);
                res.cookie('MyXSRFToken_C80', xsrfToken);

                return '/index.html';
            }

            if (req.method === 'GET' && req.url.includes('login') && !req.url.includes('google')) {
                res.cookie('MyXSRFToken', xsrfToken);
                res.cookie('MyXSRFToken_C80', xsrfToken);

                return '/';
            }
        }
    }
    },
    public: 'local.myapp.io:3000'
};
```

I have tried:

- Using the [devServer.client.logging configuration option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#logging), but this only changes what is shown in the browser console (not the command-line terminal).
- Adding the [logLevel configuration option](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/devserver-proxy-in-vue-config-js-not-working/87316/3) to the corresponding proxy configuration object (i.e. object with key `^(?!/(js|modules|img))` above), but this only seems to *increase* the amount of logging (info as well as errors).

I suspect something needs to be suppressed at a lower level, and perhaps some bash-script magic is the only plausible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround that I eventually settled on was intercepting `process.stdout.write` in the Javascript file that configured and ran the dev server/tests. Since our `test` command is implemented as a Vue CLI plugin, I could just put the override function in that plugin's `module.exports` as follows:

```
module.exports = (api, options) => {
    api.registerCommand(
        'customTestCommand',
        {
            description: 'A test command for posting on Stack Overflow',
            usage: 'vue-cli-service customTestCommand [options]',
            options: {
                '--headless': 'run in headless mode without GUI'
                ...
            }
        },
        async (args, rawArgs) => {
            // Do other setup work here

            process.stdout.write = (function (write) {
                let clearBlankLine = false;

                return function (...args) {
                    const string = args[0];
                    const isProxyError = !!string.match(/Proxy error:|ECONNRESET/);
                    const hasContent = !!string.trim();

                    if (isProxyError) {
                        clearBlankLine = true;

                        return;
                    }

                    if (!clearBlankLine || hasContent) {
                        write.apply(process.stdout, args);
                    }

                    clearBlankLine = false;
                };
            }(process.stdout.write));

            // Wait to run your actual dev server process and test commands
            // Until here.
        }
    );
};
```

This maintains all coloring, spacing, history clearing, etc. on the command line output, but any line that has the terms `Proxy Error` or `ECONNRESET` are removed. You can customize the regex to your specific needs.

For a more detailed example of intercepting both stdout and stderr, as well as redirecting those outputs to different locations (e.g. files), see the following Github gist by Ben Buckman that inspired my solution: https://gist.github.com/benbuckman/2758563

Answer (score 0):

You could add a filter at the top of the test, or globally in `/cypress/support/index.js`.

```js
Cypress.on('window:before:load', window => {
  const originalConsoleLog = window.console.log;
  window.console.log = (msg) => {
    const isProxyError = msg.includes('ECONNRESET') || msg.startsWith('Proxy error:');
    if (!isProxyError) {
      originalConsoleLog(msg)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I believe this solution only affects the browser console. In this case, I am concerned with the terminal in which the test process (and dev server) is running. Usually the test suite runs headless, so the only available output is the desktop's command line.

Comment: Yes this would only suppress browser console messages.